# JS Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting this error when I try running it on Chrome. I tried everything, but I checked back and declared the variables. I don't know what's wrong. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

The source code is bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Difference Engine</title>
    <style>
        table td, th{border: 1.5px solid black;}
        table th{background-color: lightgrey; padding: 5px;}
    </style>
    <script>
    var X,Y,dY,d2Y,d3Y,d4Y,d5y,bX,bY,bdY,bd2Y,bd3Y,bd3Y,bd4Y,bd5Y;
        X=0,
        Y=0,
        dY=0,
        d2Y=0,
        d3Y=0,
        d4Y=0,
        d5y=0,
        bX=document.getElementById('rX');
        bY=document.getElementById('rY');
        bdY=document.getElementById('rdY');
        bd2Y=document.getElementById('rd2Y');
        bd3Y=document.getElementById('rd3Y');
        bd4Y=document.getElementById('rd4Y');
        bd5Y=document.getElementById('rd5Y');

    function sum() {
        X=Number(document.getElementById('X').value)+1;
        Y=Number(document.getElementById('Y').value);
        dY=Number(document.getElementById('dY').value);
        d2Y=Number(document.getElementById('d2Y').value);
        d3Y=Number(document.getElementById('d3Y').value);
        d4Y=Number(document.getElementById('d4Y').value);
        d5Y=Number(document.getElementById('d5Y').value);

        for (X; X < Number(document.getElementById('numRows').value); X++) {
            Y+=dY;
            dY+=d2Y;
            d2Y+=d3Y;
            d3Y+=d4Y;
            d4Y+=d5Y;

            bX.value=X+"\n";
            bY.value=Y+"\n";
            bdY.value=dY+"\n";
            bd2Y.value=d2Y+"\n";
            bd3Y.value=d3Y+"\n";
            bd4Y.value=d4Y+"\n";
            bd5Y.value=d5Y+"\n";
        }
    }
    function reset(){

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#F5DEB3">
<center>
    <h1>The Babbage Difference Engine Simulator</h1>
    <h3>This is a simulation for the DIfference Engine first proposed by Charles Babbage</h3>
    Rows: <input type="number" id="numRows">
    <button id="run" onclick="sum()">Run</button>
    <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    <br>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;<sup>2</sup>Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;<sup>3</sup>Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;<sup>4</sup>Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;<sup>5</sup>Y</th>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="number" id="X" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="Y" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="dY" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="d2Y" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="d3Y" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="d4Y" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="d5Y" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><textarea id="rX" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rY" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rdY" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rd2Y" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rd3Y" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rd4Y" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rd5Y" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what line number is the error occurring on?

Comment: pwolaq has your answer, in short. your script is running before the elements are all created. I usually set my element variables in `window.onload` function so I know all the elements are loaded before using `getElementById`

Comment: instead of using `window.onload` you should use `DOMContentLoaded` event which doesn't wait for resources to load because it is not neccessary

Comment: How would i go about adding those events? I am a noob and don't know a lot. Sorry.

Comment: Also, chrome says the error is happening on line 44 which is " bX.value=X+"\n"; " inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the script before the DOM has a chance to create the elements you want to operate on. Move the script after your body is finished.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Difference Engine</title>
    <style>
        table td, th{border: 1.5px solid black;}
        table th{background-color: lightgrey; padding: 5px;}
    </style>
    
</head>
<body bgcolor="#F5DEB3">
<center>
    <h1>The Babbage Difference Engine Simulator</h1>
    <h3>This is a simulation for the DIfference Engine first proposed by Charles Babbage</h3>
    Rows: <input type="number" id="numRows">
    <button id="run" onclick="sum()">Run</button>
    <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    <br>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;<sup>2</sup>Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;<sup>3</sup>Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;<sup>4</sup>Y</th>
        <th>&Delta;<sup>5</sup>Y</th>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="number" id="X" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="Y" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="dY" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="d2Y" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="d3Y" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="d4Y" /></th>
        <th><input type="number" id="d5Y" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><textarea id="rX" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rY" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rdY" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rd2Y" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rd3Y" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rd4Y" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea id="rd5Y" rows="35" cols="23"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</center>
</body>
<script>
    var X,Y,dY,d2Y,d3Y,d4Y,d5y,bX,bY,bdY,bd2Y,bd3Y,bd3Y,bd4Y,bd5Y;
        X=0,
        Y=0,
        dY=0,
        d2Y=0,
        d3Y=0,
        d4Y=0,
        d5y=0,
        bX=document.getElementById('rX');
        bY=document.getElementById('rY');
        bdY=document.getElementById('rdY');
        bd2Y=document.getElementById('rd2Y');
        bd3Y=document.getElementById('rd3Y');
        bd4Y=document.getElementById('rd4Y');
        bd5Y=document.getElementById('rd5Y');

    function sum() {
        X=Number(document.getElementById('X').value)+1;
        Y=Number(document.getElementById('Y').value);
        dY=Number(document.getElementById('dY').value);
        d2Y=Number(document.getElementById('d2Y').value);
        d3Y=Number(document.getElementById('d3Y').value);
        d4Y=Number(document.getElementById('d4Y').value);
        d5Y=Number(document.getElementById('d5Y').value);

        for (X; X < Number(document.getElementById('numRows').value); X++) {
            Y+=dY;
            dY+=d2Y;
            d2Y+=d3Y;
            d3Y+=d4Y;
            d4Y+=d5Y;

            bX.value=X+"\n";
            bY.value=Y+"\n";
            bdY.value=dY+"\n";
            bd2Y.value=d2Y+"\n";
            bd3Y.value=d3Y+"\n";
            bd4Y.value=d4Y+"\n";
            bd5Y.value=d5Y+"\n";
        }
    }
    function reset(){

    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did work after all. I am having another problem with the source code now, ask about that do I start another question or do I just ask a follow-up question?

Comment: @all thanks for the feedback and answers, I didn't understand the answers for other posts. that's why I tempted to post another question.

Comment: @SreekuttanSudarsanan if it worked, accept the answer :) if the followup question is about my code, ask it here. If it's a different question about your code, ask another question :)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to StackOverflow. I marked the answer right. I did find what I did wrong so its fine, thank you.

Comment: That's quite alright, welcome to SO!